# Invoke a method via MethodInfo Problem

Tags: c#, reflection, types

I get the class name and method name as well as parameters via query string. I don't know what is coming so I can't say lets create this instance  or that instance to pass it `MethodInfo Invoke` method so I need a generic solution. Here is the problem :

```
string className = Request.QueryString["className"];
string actionMethod = Request.QueryString["actionName"];
```

so I have to invoke a class method by the info above :

```
System.Reflection.MethodInfo info = Type.GetType(className).GetMethod(actionMethod);
info.Invoke(obj, null);
```

But since I don't know what it is coming from the `QueryString` I can't create an instance of the class of which I want to invoke the method.

How can I get over this problem...

Comment: You know, it almost looks like you're reinventing ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: BTW, you **really** want to sanitise any input that - accepting *any* type and method is just an open door, looking for abuse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the assembly that contains the class you are invoking, you can use `Assembly.CreateInstance(string)` to create your instance of the class.

*Code not tested*

```
object myObject = Assembly.CreateInstance(typeName);
MethodInfo info = Type.GetType(className).GetMethod(actionMethod);
info.Invoke(myObject, null);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.createinstance.aspx

Comment: You can also use Activator.CreateInstance() to acheive the same results.

Answer (score 1):

> But since I don't know what it is coming from the QueryString I can't create an instance of the class of which I want to invoke the method.

Why not? You know the type of the object. Just call the default constructor and you have your instance.

An instance method *requires an instance of the object*. No two ways around that. Looking back at all the instance methods you've written, would it even *make sense* to call them without an actual object instance behind them?

Comment: Can you give me an example of something ? If I knew how to do that I wouldn't ask it here :)

Comment: `System.Reflection.MethodInfo info = Type.GetType(className).GetMethod(actionMethod); info.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(className)), null);`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am having difficulty understanding the issue here.

If it is you don't know what parameters have been passed into the query string, you could have a constructor / method signature that simply took the query string then parsed it internally.

**EDIT**

If it is your own class, you can write a method or constructor with a single string or object input, then parse it either with a regex, or a string split on '='

If it is not your class to modify, you will need to create a helper class to act as a factory for the object you are trying to create to do the same thing.